# How can i replace the value of a variable with a value from another variable in a while loop

Tags: java

How can I replace the value of a variable with a value from another variable in a loop? I'm trying to replace the value of variable heightn with the value of variable fluidheight in a loop, the base value for heightn is 20 but as soon as 1 loop is completed (wherein the fluidheight is finally calculated), it will immediately change the value of heightn with the value of fluidheight. I've tried doing heightn = fluidheight and vice versa and placed the line of code in multiple locations but it still doesnt work. It always assumes that heightn is 20 after multiple loops. Any tips or suggestions?

```
    double heightn = 20;
    double g = 0;
    double sqt = heightn/2;
    double areaofnozzle = 0.0218209;
    double time = 0;
    double velocity;
    double volumelost;
    double totalvolume = 1005.309;
    double fluidheight = heightn;
    int x = 0;

    while (x < 2)
    {
        while (sqt!= g)
    {

        g=sqt;

        sqt = (heightn/g+g)/2;


    }
    time = time + 60;

    velocity = 8.02 * sqt;

    volumelost = (velocity * areaofnozzle) * time;

    fluidheight = (totalvolume - volumelost)/ 50.265;

    x = x + 1;
    System.out.println("Volume Lost = "+ volumelost);
    //System.out.println("Fluid Height = "+ fluidheight);
    System.out.println("Time = "+ time);
    System.out.println("Squre Root = "+ sqt);
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println("HeightN = "+ heightn);

    heightn = fluidheight;
    }
```

Comment: you could do an if statement inside the loop. When the value you are looking for is equal to one of the values you are looping you can assign the new variable inside this statement

Comment: This is a good opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger.  The code is not "assuming" anything.  It's doing *exactly* what it's told.  *You* are likely making assumptions or relying on false understandings.  When you use a debugger, you can step through the code line by line as it executes and *observe* exactly what it's doing, exactly what values are in your variables, how each line of code changes those values, etc.  When you do this, which exact line of code first produces an unexpected result.  What were the values?  What was the result?  What did you expect?  Why?

Comment: I just ran your code, and don't understand the problem. I mean, after a single iteration, HeightN isn't 20 anymore.

Comment: i also copy pasted your code and after 20 iterations my heightN = 2.25. How do you increase iterations?

Comment: same as two from above, may be the way you iterate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few suggestions:

1. Formatting and readability matter a lot.  Learn Java coding standards and pay more attention to brace placement, consistent indenting, etc.  Code that's hard to read is hard to understand.
2. Looks like you're doing some simple fluids calculations here, but your naming for variables is hard to follow.  Think more about better names.
3. Comparing doubles using equality is dangerous.  Better to use absolute values of differences and tolerances.  Floating point numbers are not exact.

I've figured out that you're trying to calculate the height of fluid in a tank as a function of time when it's being drained from a nozzle at the bottom of the tank.

You derive the equation from conservation of mass:

```
Rate of change of mass stored = Rate of mass in - Rate of mass out
```

The rate of change of mass stored equals the area of the tank (looking down at it) times the rate of change of the height of the liquid per unit time.  I don't restrict the shape of the area or perimeter of the tank, but I assume straight sides: the cross-sectional area does not change with height.

The rate of mass in is zero.

The rate of mass out is the mass flow out through the nozzle.  It's derived from Bernoulli's equation.

It's a first order ordinary differential equation.  You're using the simplest integration scheme possible: explicit Euler integration with a fixed time step.

Here's my solution:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

/**
 * Euler integration of first order ODE for emptying a tank through a nozzle.
 * User: mduffy
 * Date: 12/7/18
 * Time: 7:54 AM
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53669186/how-can-i-replace-the-value-of-a-variable-with-a-value-from-another-variable-in/53669375?noredirect=1#comment94196737_53669375
 */
public class Hydraulics {

    private static final double AREA_TANK = 1005.39/20.0;
    private static final double AREA_NOZZLE = 0.0218209;
    private static final double MASS_RATE_CONSTANT = 8.02;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double height = 20.0;
        int time = 0;
        int dt = 60;
        double tolerance = 1.0e-1;
        Map<Integer, Double> results = new TreeMap<>();
        while (height > tolerance) {
            results.put(time, height);
            height += derivative(time, height)*dt;
            time += dt;
        }
        System.out.println("Time  Height");
        for (int t : results.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%5d %10.3f", t, results.get(t)));
        }
    }

    private static double derivative(int time, double height) {
        return -MASS_RATE_CONSTANT*AREA_NOZZLE*Math.sqrt(height)/AREA_TANK;
    }
}
```

Here is my result.  If that time step is in seconds, it takes about 39 minutes to drain my pool:

```
Time  Height
    0     20.000
   60     19.066
  120     18.154
  180     17.264
  240     16.396
  300     15.550
  360     14.726
  420     13.925
  480     13.145
  540     12.388
  600     11.653
  660     10.940
  720     10.249
  780      9.580
  840      8.934
  900      8.309
  960      7.707
 1020      7.127
 1080      6.570
 1140      6.034
 1200      5.521
 1260      5.031
 1320      4.562
 1380      4.116
 1440      3.692
 1500      3.291
 1560      2.912
 1620      2.555
 1680      2.221
 1740      1.910
 1800      1.621
 1860      1.356
 1920      1.112
 1980      0.892
 2040      0.695
 2100      0.521
 2160      0.370
 2220      0.243
 2280      0.140
 2340      0.062
```

The volume lost over any time step is equal to the change in height times the tank area, which is `AREA_TANK = 1005.39/20.0`.

The change in volume is (19.066-20)*1005.39/20 = -46.9517 over the first time step.  It drops to (0.062-0.140)*1005.39/20 = -3.9210 by the last time step.  The rate slows down because the static pressure at the nozzle exit goes down as the height of the liquid in the pool drops.

Wondering where the square root of the height comes from?  Hint: Bernoulli's equation for the nozzle says the exit velocity is proportional to the square root of the static pressure at the nozzle, which is proportional to the height of the water left in the tank.

Comment: The results of the program should be that the variable Squre (Square) Root shouldn't be the same as the first print because 4.721..... is the square root of 20. I'm trying to replace 20 with the second HeightN which is 19.065 and if it is changed, the Volume Lost should be 45.84. I'm sorry but im just a high school student, I'm not very good at Java

Comment: Square root of what?  I'm guessing this is a conservation of mass, tank emptying problem.   You start with a fluid at initial height and open a valve to drain it.  You know the exit velocity and exit pressure is related to the height of the fluid above the value, so the rate of fluid out of the tank decreases as the height of the fluid in the tank drops.  Is that right?  If yes, you're solving a first order ordinary differential equation for the height of the fluid in the tank as a function of time.  High school?  Really?

Comment: the formula is  velocity = 8.02 * (square root of the height of fluid in the tank which is 20) which is then used to calculate volume lost which is volume lost = velocity  * (area of the nozzle) * time and once it is calculated volume lost will be used to subtract totalvolume which will then affect the fluid height and the loop repeats until the fluid height is at 0 feet.

Comment: The height of the fluid in the tank might be 20 when you start, but it drops as fluid flows out.  The 20 value is only the initial condition.  I think hydraulics would say that the velocity is a function of the height of the liquid remaining in the tank.

Comment: Your starting with conservation of mass: rate of change of mass in the tank = -Rate of mass out through the nozzle.  The left hand side is A x dH/dt, where A = area of the tank.  The right hand side is rho x A x velocity, where this A is the area of the nozzle and the velocity is 8.02*sqrt(H).  You're doing Euler integration, where you solve for dH/dt and approximate it using a difference equation.  Looks like you assumed 60 for a time step.  How did you decide that?  Stability?

Comment: time is increased at intervals of 1 minute so 60 seconds is added at each loop. That's why the volume lost increases because time is continually increasing while the velocity stays the same when it should decrease. It continues to use 20 as heightn

Comment: Right, you need to make that value equal to the instantaneous height, not 20.  That's only the initial value.  The amount of fluid lost should also be multiplied by your time step, not the total time.  You should only have one loop, not two.

Comment: Yes that is correct ,here's an image of the problem if it will help you understand more. https://imgur.com/B0NSTSj

Comment: I don't need the image.  I think I understand this problem better than you do.

Comment: but why one loop? I need to do a certain amount of loops until fluid height is at 0.

Comment: One loop to start at a height of 20 and iterate until the value is within a tolerance of zero.  That's all.

Comment: So I must create a separate loop statement for the initial height which is 20 then another loop statement for the rest of the heights? I'm sorry but I'm really having a difficult time understanding.

Comment: No, one loop to change the height and time at the end if each time step. You start at time = 0 and height = 20. You calculate the change of height over a time step inside the loop and update the time and height. Iterate until the height is less than it equal to zero

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks man, now I just gotta try to understand. Cheers!

Comment: Don't try to hand this into your professor.  They'll know you didn't do this.  Even if you're taking calculus you are unlikely to know what Euler integration or first order ordinary differential equations are.

Comment: I know but I really appreciate the help! I'll just try to understand it and hopefully make use of the while loop for this program.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I replace the value of a variable with a value from another variable **in a loop**?

To replace the value of a variable `A` with the value from another variable `B` you do this:

```
A = B; // After the execution of this line, the value of B will be assigned to A
```

It doesn't really matter if it is in a loop or not, that doesn't change anything.

> I'm trying to replace the value of variable `heightn` with the value of variable `fluidheight` in a loop

In your case, that would look like this:

```
heightn = fluidheight; // The value of fluidheight will be assigned to heightn
```

I think that your confusion with the first iteration might be that you are displaying the value of `heightn` **before** you change it. Therefore, after the first execution you will always see in the standard output that the value of `heightn` is `20` at the moment.

- In the first execution of the loop you will see `20`.
- In the second execution of the loop you will see the result of first execution.
- The (final) result of the second execution is never shown.

I suggest that you change that you change that part like this:

```
heightn = fluidheight;
System.out.println("Volume Lost = " + volumelost);
System.out.println("Time = " + time);
System.out.println("Squre Root = " + sqt);
System.out.println(" ");
System.out.println("HeightN = " + heightn);
```

Finally, like @David said in the comments, this is the typical case in which you should leverage the use of a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You assign value of heightn in last line of loop. But output value of this var before assigning new value. Add

```
System.out.println("HeightN = "+ heightn);
```

**after** loop and you will see variable value after calculation in loop, or simple swap last two lines of code (println and assigning value)